# How to align two images based on a common feature with matchTemplate

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0, template-matching

I have two images which overlap. I'd like to align these two images. My current approach is to find a common feature (a marking) in both images. I'd then like to align these two images according to the place where the feature overlaps.

The images aren't perfect, so I'm looking for some way that will align based the 'best' fit (most overlap). Originally I tried to align the images using feature matching through SIFT but the features matches were often incorrect/too few.

Here's the code I used to find the [template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6ivR.jpg):

```
template = cv2.imread('template.png', 0)
template = template - cv2.erode(template, None)

image1 = cv2.imread('Image to align1.png')
image2 = cv2.imread('Image to align2.png')
image = image2
img2 = image[:,:,2]
img2 = img2 - cv2.erode(img2, None)

ccnorm = cv2.matchTemplate(img2, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
print(ccnorm.max())
loc = np.where(ccnorm == ccnorm.max())
print(loc)
threshold = 0.1
th, tw = template.shape[:2]
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    if ccnorm[pt[::-1]] < threshold:
        continue
    cv2.rectangle(image, pt, (pt[0] + tw, pt[1] + th),
                 (0, 0, 255), 2)
```

Here are the matched features, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynUGz.jpg) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4tf6.jpg).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to simply shift the image and overlap, or do you want to warp it (with possible scaling, rotation, and perspective distortion)?

Comment: You may refer to this [post](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I'm capturing images through a glass screen using a handheld camera/scanner pressed against the screen, so I'm assuming that shift and rotation are the only differences between my images.

Comment: @ZdaR Thanks for the link, unfortunately that was the original approach that I mentioned in my OP using SIFT and feature detection. Do you have any resources for a template-based approach for image alignment/stitching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your choices with the OpenCV library is to use any number of methods to select a few points, and create the transformation between those points in the image by using a function like [`getAffineTransform`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getaffinetransform) or [`getPerspectiveTransform`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#getperspectivetransform). Note that functions like these take *points* as arguments, *not* luminosity values (images). You'll want to find points of interest in the first image (say, those marker spots); and you'll want to find those same points in the second image, and pass *those* pixel locations to a function like `getAffineTransform` or `getPerspectiveTransform`. Then, once you have that transformation matrix, you can use [`warpAffine`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpaffine) or [`warpPerspective`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#warpperspective) to warp the second image into the coordinates of the first (or vice versa).

*Affine* transformations include translation, rotation, scaling, and shearing. *Perspective* transformations include everything from affine transformations, as well as perspective distortion in the `x` and `y` directions. For `getAffineTransform` you need to send three pairs of points from the first image, and where those three same pixels are located in the second image. For `getPerspectiveTransform`, you will send four pixel pairs from each image. If you want to use all of your marker points, you can use [`findHomography`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography) instead which will allow you to place *more* than four points and it will compute an optimal homography between all of your matched points.

When you use feature detection and matching to align images, it's using these functions in the background. The difference is it finds the features for you. But if that's not working, simply use manual methods to find the features to your liking, and then use these methods on those feature points. E.g., you could find the template locations as you already have and define that as a region of interest (ROI), and then break the marker points into smaller template pieces and find those locations inside your ROI. Then you have corresponding pairs of points from both images; you can input their locations into `findHomography` or just pick three to use with `getAffineTransform` or four with `getPerspectiveTransform` and you'll get your image transformation which you can then apply.

---

Otherwise you'll need to use something like the [Lukas-Kanade optical flow algorithm](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=opticalflowpyrlk#cv.CalcOpticalFlowPyrLK) which can do direct image matching if you don't want to use feature-based methods, but these are incredibly slow comparatively to selecting a few feature points and finding homographies that way if you use the whole image. However if you only have to do it for a few images, it's not such a huge deal. To be more accurate and have it converge much faster, it'll help if you can provide it a starting homography that at least translates it roughly to the right position (e.g. you do your feature detection, see that the feature is roughly `(x', y')` pixels in the second image from the first, and create an homography with that translation).

You can also likely find some Python routines for homography estimation from the Lucas-Kanade inverse compositional algorithm or the like online if you want to try that. I have my own custom routine for that algorithm as well, but I can't share it, however, I could run the algorithm on your images if you share the originals without the bounding boxes, to maybe provide you with some estimated homographies to compare with.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed comment and the offer to compare notes. I'll give your approach a shot and supply some images for comparison once I have a working solution. Were you able to write your routine in Python or did you write it in C++?

Comment: Python. Also Matlab separately. I cannot share it as I developed it at a job, but you can find many implementations online. Check out [menpofit](https://github.com/menpo/menpofit) which has multiple variants of the Lucas-Kanade algorithm, programmed nicely. The Inverse Compositional method is the fastest. But I think the feature based methods should work perfectly for you if you write your own feature selector.

Comment: @Jason do you have python code for this ???? or any one can please add the code as answer as well.

Comment: @M.D.P see https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/dff/tutorial_feature_homography.html and https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html and search online for "opencv homography" and "opencv alignment"---there are a lot of tutorials out there. Open up a new question if you have trouble implementing those tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Homography.
Here's an article on what you're looking for(along with code in both C++ & Python):
[Feature Based Image Alignment Using OpenCV](https://learnopencv.com/feature-based-image-alignment-using-opencv-c-python)